# pyspark window min(date) and max(date) of group

Tags: pyspark, group-by, window, partition

i have dataset

| user | date | loc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2021-01-01 | 1 |
| a | 2021-01-02 | 1 |
| a | 2021-01-03 | 2 |
| a | 2021-01-04 | 2 |
| a | 2021-01-05 | 1 |
| a | 2021-01-06 | 1 |

i am trying to end up with

| user | startdate | enddate | loc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-02 | 1 |
| a | 2021-01-03 | 2021-01-04 | 2 |
| a | 2021-01-05 | 2021-01-06 | 1 |

I have tried window partition over[user,loc].order by date
row_number
and I tried lag check if prevrow loc = current loc and then increment the value
but I am stuck.
does anyone have a solution to this grouping issue. Not sure why it is so hard for me to figure out

thanks for any help

Comment: thank you for fixing the formating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to approach the problem

- Create a helper `group` column to distinguish between the consecutive rows in `loc` per `user`
- Then group the dataframe by the columns `user`, `loc` and `group` and aggregate the column `date` using `min` and `max`
- Drop the `group` column and sort the dataframe by `startdate`

```
w = Window.partitionBy('user').orderBy('date')
b = F.lag('loc').over(w) != F.col('loc')

(
    df.withColumn('group', b.cast('int'))
      .fillna(0, 'group')
      .withColumn('group', F.sum('group').over(w))
      .groupBy('user', 'loc', 'group')
      .agg(F.min('date').alias('startdate'), 
           F.max('date').alias('enddate'))
      .drop('group')
      .orderBy('startdate')
)
```

---

```
+----+---+----------+----------+
|user|loc| startdate|   enddate|
+----+---+----------+----------+
|   a|  1|2021-01-01|2021-01-02|
|   a|  2|2021-01-03|2021-01-04|
|   a|  1|2021-01-05|2021-01-06|
+----+---+----------+----------+
```

Comment: This worked fantastic, thank you for taking the time to help.